# Displaying questions in a questionnaire using PHP?

Tags: php

I am building an online questionnaire. In this questionnaire, **the user should see only one question at a time per page**. When he sees the question, he will provide an answer and after that he will press on next to go to the second question and so on until the end of the questionnaire. I have already built the questionnaire but I am stuck now on the part" how i can display only one question from the database?". Also, when the user press on next, should i save the answer immediately to the database or I should wait until he completes answering all the questions and save them at the end to the database?

If anyone can help in that, please provide me with the appropriate technique to do that in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable that matches all the question ids (hope you have unique ids for each of your question).

And then loop through that variable and for each counter value fetch the data from the database using `where id = ?` clause where `?` will be replaced by the counter variable value.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and helpful answer. Should I insert all the answers into the database at the end of the questionnaire or one answer at a time when I go through the questions?

Comment: I think temporarily saving the answers and then inserting all of them will be good from performance perspective. I don't know much about it.

Comment: I really appreciate your answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think I will wait before accepting the answer. Other people might answer it in a different way or technique. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't mean that you accept my answer, I found that you are a new user so just wanted to let you know that you should accept answer.

Comment: And i am sure you will get better answers by time.